# How can I get list of special member, which including in MyClass, from a List<MyClass>?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have next code:

```
public class MyClass
{
   object field1;
   object field2;
}

///////
List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();
GetLstMember(lst, "field1");

///////
List<object> GetLstMember(List<Object> lst, string memberName)
{
      List<object> rezult = new List<object>();

      for(int i=0; i<lst.Count; i++)
      {
           rezult.Add(lst[i].GetType().InvokeMember(
               memberName, 
               BindingFlag.GetProperty, 
               null,
               lst[i],
               null);
      }

      return rezult;
}
```

Whether there is other way to write method `GetLstMember` without using reflection? I tried to use `BindingSource` without success:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(lst, memberName);
return bs.List;
```

Ok, I understand to use reflection. Is there a difference in performance in such code and previous :

```
List<object> GetLstMember(List<Object> lst, string memberName) 
{ 
     List<object> rezult = new List<object>(); 
     for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++) 
       rezult.Add(lst[i].GetType().GetProperty(memberName).GetValue(lst[i],null)**); 
     return rezult; 
}
```

Comment: This is a very poor way to go about this. Use a `Dictionary<string,object>` instead of 'MyClass'

Comment: It depends.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does your field name have to be a string? If not, you can use LINQ: `data = lst.Select(m => m.field1).ToList();`

Comment: Why don't you want to use reflection? If it's because of performance, we could talk about some ways to offset that cost. If it's because reflection looks a bit messy, it could be re-factored to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

That's the only way to do it; this is what reflection is for.

Even if you use a BindingList, it would also use reflection.
Also, BindingList cannot actually do that.

Comment: I thought that maybe exist special classes for such things.

Comment: Yes.  It's called Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on .net 4, you can used the the dynamic keyword. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Something like this should work.

```
public class MyClass {
    object field1;
    object field2;
}

///////
List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();
GetLstMember(lst);
///////
List<object> GetLstMember(List<dynamic> lst, string memberName)
{
      List<object> rezult=new List<object>();
      for(int i=0;i<lst.Count;i++){
            switch(memberName){
                case "field1":
                    rezult.Add(lst[i].field1);
                break;
                case "field2":
                    rezult.Add(lst[i].field2);
                break;          
            }
        }
    return rezult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, is there a difference in performance in

```
lst[i].GetType().GetProperty(memberName).GetValue(lst[i],null)

lst[i].GetType().InvokeMember(memberName, BindingFlag.GetProperty, null, lst[i], null)
```

?